# Row Formula relation in Excel

Tags: excel

Is there a way to make connection between the formula and a number in the cell

As Example If we have a number 5 the formula take information from cell A5, If the number is 33 to take information A33. I want to make relation between different sheets.

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

You could use Row() and Column()

I use this formula a lot to enumerate rows that have a thing we need

=ALS(IF(B15<>"";C15<>"";D15<>"";B15<>"");RIJ()-4;"")